# Is is possible to configure cppcheck as your linter for nano?

Tags: debugging, nano

Good debugging tools can save you a lot of time when you are writing code. In nano, it's nice that with bash scripts, you can just hit <kbd>alt+b</kbd> to find syntax errors before you try running it.

However, I would like to know if you can use cppcheck as your linter for C/C++ files in the c.nanorc file. In the nano manual, this is the syntax for adding linters to syntax files:

`linter program [argument …]`

I tried `linter cppcheck`, but got no results. I still get the error warning about a linter not being configured for .c files.